# Get constructor index using generics in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to implement the following typeclass with the generics:

```
class HasIndex a where
   getIndex :: a -> Int
```

So, for the given data type

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGenerics #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Binary    

data Test = Foo Int | Bar deriving (Generic)
instance Binary Test
instance HasIndex Test
```

the call

```
getIndex $ Foo 1
```

should return 0. And

```
getIndex Bar
```

should return 1. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to automatically generate something like `getIndex (Foo _) = 0; getIndex Bar = 1`?

Comment: So you're saying when you `derive Binary` it works, but you want to understand how?

Comment: Not quite. I want to send arbitrary data from the browser encoded in binary format and deserialize it to the user defined data structure. In other words, I need to construct binary stream on the client side.

Comment: `ghc-prim` _does_ have a `dataToTag# :: a -> Int#`... 3:)

Comment: `ghc-prim` is too "low level". It is possible to achieve what I want with `Data.Data` module, but generics seem more "elegant".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there's no real problem with using both `Data` and `Generic` generics in the same program, and sometimes -- as here -- `Data` is more convenient.

Anyway, here's the idea for a pure `Generic` solution.  The general approach, as described in GHC.Generics, is to define a generic function:

```
getIndex :: (Generic a, GetIndex' (Rep a)) => a -> Int
getIndex = getIndex' . from
```

that dispatches to the appropriate `GetIndex'` instance on the representation and then define `GetIndex'` instances for all of the generics constructors.

Suppose we start with a class like:

```
class GetIndex' f where
  getIndex' :: f p -> Int
```

and try to define the `(:+:)` instance.  This is easy if the provided value is on the left-hand side because the index within `f :+: g` will just be the index within `f`, so we have:

```
instance (GetIndex' f, GetIndex' g) => GetIndex' (f :+: g) where
  getIndex' (L1 x) = getIndex' x
```

When we try to define it for the right-hand side, though, we run into a problem:

```
  getIndex' (R1 x) = <<size f>> + getIndex' x
```

We need to calculate the size of the left-hand side from its representation `f`.  The standard way of doing this is to define a `size` method that takes a proxy argument, so we'll modify our class to look like:

```
class GetIndex' f where
  getIndex' :: f p -> Int
  size :: Proxy f -> Int
```

Now, we can write:

```
instance (GetIndex' f, GetIndex' g) => GetIndex' (f :+: g) where
  getIndex' (L1 x) = getIndex' x
  getIndex' (R1 x) = size (Proxy @f) + getIndex' x
  size _ = size (Proxy @f) + size (Proxy @g)
```

Product terms `(:*:)` and the unit terms `U1` and `K1` will all represent the single-constructor case, so they will all have similar instances:

```
instance GetIndex' U1 where
  getIndex' _ = 0
  size _ = 1
```

The complete program will look something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Proxy

class GetIndex' f where
  getIndex' :: f p -> Int
  size :: Proxy f -> Int
instance (GetIndex' f) => GetIndex' (M1 i t f) where
  getIndex' (M1 x) = getIndex' x
  size _ = size (Proxy @f)
instance GetIndex' V1 where
  getIndex' v = case v of
  -- Unused, but consistent
  size _ = 0
instance (GetIndex' f, GetIndex' g) => GetIndex' (f :+: g) where
  getIndex' (L1 x) = getIndex' x
  getIndex' (R1 x) = size (Proxy @f) + getIndex' x
  size _ = size (Proxy @f) + size (Proxy @g)
instance GetIndex' (f :*: g) where
  getIndex' _ = 0
  size _ = 1
instance GetIndex' (K1 i c) where
  getIndex' _ = 0
  size _ = 1
instance GetIndex' U1 where
  getIndex' _ = 0
  size _ = 1

getIndex :: (Generic a, GetIndex' (Rep a)) => a -> Int
getIndex = getIndex' . from

data Test = Foo Int | Bar deriving (Generic)

main = do
  print $ getIndex (Foo 999)
  print $ getIndex Bar
```

Comment: Thank you. Especially for `Data.Proxy` :)

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten a lot better at this in five years:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.Generics
import GHC.Types
import GHC.TypeLits

type family CPos (cname :: Symbol) f :: Maybe Nat where
  CPos cname (D1 m f) = CPos cname f
  CPos cname (f :+: g) = Alt (CPos cname f) (FSum (CtorCount f) (CPos cname g))
  CPos cname (C1 ('MetaCons cname _ _) _) = 'Just 1
  CPos cname _ = 'Nothing

type family CtorCount f :: Nat where
  CtorCount (D1 m f) = CtorCount f
  CtorCount (f :+: g) = CtorCount f + CtorCount g
  CtorCount (C1 _ _) = 1

type family FSum (lhs :: Nat) (rhs :: Maybe Nat) :: Maybe Nat where
  FSum m ('Just n) = 'Just (m + n)
  FSum m 'Nothing = 'Nothing

type family Alt (m1 :: Maybe a) (m2 :: Maybe a) :: Maybe a where
  Alt ('Just a) _ = 'Just a 
  Alt _ b = b
```

Now we can obtain the constructor index as a type:

```
> :type Proxy :: Proxy (CPos "Foo" (Rep Test))
Proxy :: Proxy (CPos "Foo" (Rep Test)) :: Proxy ('Just 1)
> :type Proxy :: Proxy (CPos "Bar" (Rep Test))
Proxy :: Proxy (CPos "Bar" (Rep Test)) :: Proxy ('Just 2)
```

If we create a type to hold an index, we can write a getIndex function that takes no arguments, only type applications.  Thus, its value is computed at compile time rather than run time:

```
data CHop a = CHop {constrPos :: Int} deriving (Generic, Show)

getIndex ::
  forall (cname :: Symbol) (a :: *) (cpos :: Nat). (KnownNat cpos, CPos cname (Rep a) ~ 'Just cpos)
  => CHop a
getIndex = CHop (fromIntegral (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy cpos)))

> getIndex @"Just" @(Maybe Int)
CHop {constrPos = 2}
> getIndex @"Nothing" @(Maybe Int)
CHop {constrPos = 1}
```

Comment: You can use `:kind!` (note the bang) instead of using `:type` with a proxy.

Comment: With `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, you don't need `CHop`. But if you prefer that style, it's probably more idiomatic to use `Data.Tagged`.

Comment: Very clever idea of distinguishing `D1` from `C1`. I've adapted that to K. A. Buhr's approach in my own answer.

Comment: It doesn't exactly answer the original question, but in a project I'm doing I started out needing the answer to the original question and this ended up being a better answer to a better question.

Comment: It's always nice when more experience leads you to better questions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat abbreviated version of the implementation by K. A. Buhr, taking advantage of the idea in David Fox's latest answer of distinguishing `D1` (that is, `M1 D`) from `C1` (that is, `M1 C`). This obviates the need to worry about `(:*:)`, `U1`, or `K1`. I also drop the proxies in favor of `AllowAmbiguousTypes`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

import GHC.Generics

class GetIndex' f where
  getIndex' :: f p -> Int
  size :: Int

instance GetIndex' f => GetIndex' (D1 t f) where
  getIndex' (M1 x) = getIndex' x
  size = size @f

-- We've reached a constructor. It doesn't matter what it
-- looks like; the results will be the same regardless.
instance GetIndex' (C1 t f) where
  getIndex' _ = 0
  size = 1

instance GetIndex' V1 where
  getIndex' v = case v of
  size = 0

instance (GetIndex' f, GetIndex' g) => GetIndex' (f :+: g) where
  getIndex' (L1 x) = getIndex' x
  getIndex' (R1 x) = size @f + getIndex' x
  size = size @f + size @g

getIndex :: (Generic a, GetIndex' (Rep a)) => a -> Int
getIndex = getIndex' . from
```

Answer (score 1):

The package generic-data has this function:

```
> gconIndex Nothing
0
> gconIndex (Just 'x')
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2021:

```
-- |
-- @@
-- λ> :kind! (ConstructorPosition "Con2" Typ)
-- = 2
-- @@
type family ConstructorPosition (cname :: Symbol) (a :: *) :: 
Maybe Nat where
  ConstructorPosition cname a = GConstructorPosition cname (Rep a)

type family GConstructorPosition (cname :: Symbol) (f :: * -> *) :: Maybe Nat where
  GConstructorPosition cname (D1 m f) = GConstructorPosition cname f
  GConstructorPosition cname (f :+: g) = Alt (GConstructorPosition cname f) (FSum (GConstructorCount f) (GConstructorPosition cname g))
  GConstructorPosition cname (C1 ('MetaCons cname _ _) f) = 'Just 1
  GConstructorPosition cname (C1 _ f) = 'Nothing

constructorPosition :: forall cname a n. (KnownNat n, Just n ~ ConstructorPosition cname a) => Integer
constructorPosition = natVal (Proxy @n)
{-# INLINE constructorPosition #-}
```

Ended up with this:

```
instance ConsIndex Int where
  getIndex _ = undefined

class ConsIndex c where
  getIndex :: c -> Int
  default getIndex :: (Generic c, GConsIndex (Rep c)) => c -> Int
  getIndex = ggetIndex . from

class GConsIndex f where
  ggetIndex :: f t -> Int

instance GConsIndex U1 where
  ggetIndex _ = undefined

instance GConsIndex a => GConsIndex (M1 D c a) where
  ggetIndex = ggetIndex . unM1

instance GConsIndex a => GConsIndex (M1 C c a) where
  ggetIndex = ggetIndex . unM1

instance (GConsIndex a, GSum a) => GConsIndex (M1 S c a) where
  ggetIndex = ggetIndex . unM1

instance ConsIndex a => GConsIndex (K1 c a) where
  ggetIndex = getIndex . unK1

instance (GConsIndex a, GConsIndex b,
         GSum a, GSum b) => GConsIndex (a :+: b) where
  ggetIndex = gsum 0

instance (GConsIndex a, GConsIndex b, GSum a) => GConsIndex (a :*: b) where
  ggetIndex (a :*: _) = ggetIndex a

class GSum f where
  gsum :: Int -> f t -> Int

instance (GSum a, GSum b) => GSum (a :+: b) where
  gsum acc (L1 l) = acc
  gsum acc (R1 r) = gsum (acc + 1) r

instance (GSum a) => GSum (M1 C c a) where
  gsum x = (gsum x) . unM1

instance (GSum a) => GSum (M1 S c a) where
  gsum x = (gsum x) . unM1

instance GSum (K1 c a) where
  gsum x _ = x

instance GSum U1 where
  gsum acc _ = acc

instance (GSum a, GSum b) => GSum (a :*: b) where
  gsum x _ = x

data Test = Foo | Bar Int | Baz Int Int deriving (Show, Generic)
instance ConsIndex Test
```